# Extender el modelo de Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

El problema lo tengo no en extender el modelo de Django es que necesito crear más de un tipo de usuario en concreto dos Estudiante y Profesor cada uno con atributos en común pero con otros propios de cada uno, alguien me pudiera dar alguna idea o ejemplo.

Model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from Perfiles import settings


class User(AbstractUser):
     is_estudiante = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     is_profesor = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def get_estudiante_profile(self):
        estudiante_profile = None
        if hasattr(self, 'estudianteprofile'):
            estudiante_profile = self.estudianteprofile
        return estudiante_profile

    def get_profesor_profile(self):
         profesor_profile = None
    if hasattr(self, 'profesorprofile'):
        profesor_profile = self.profesorprofile
    return profesor_profile

class Meta:
    db_table = 'auth_user'


class EstudianteProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    anno = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    carrera = models.CharField(max_length=64)


class ProfesorProfile(models.Model):
   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   departamento = models.CharField(max_length=64)
   asignatura = models.CharField(max_length=64)


@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
   def create_profile_for_new_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
      if instance.is_estudiante:
         profile = EstudianteProfile(user=instance)
         profile.save()

     elif instance.is_profesor:
        profile = ProfesorProfile(user=instance)
        profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede hacer añadiendo un FK al los modelos Estudiante y Profesor de User o por herencia 'class Profesor (User): ' para crear el modelo profesor de la misma forma con estudiantes. Si pones tu código te puedo dar una respuesta más específica.

Lo has estado haciendo bien solo tienes que crear dos modelos uno para cada tipo de usuario que deseas:

```
class Profesor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    puesto = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    edad = models.IntegerField(default=0)


class Estudiante(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tutor = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
    phone_tutor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

El `model.OneToOneField` lo que es hace es relacionar el model estudiante o profesor con User de django y con esto puedes acceder a los atributos de User de Django desde estudiante o profesor

```
views.py
try:
    profesor = Profesor.objects.get(user=request.user)
    print profesor.puesto
    prinf profesor.user.first_name
    #podrias haber accedido al first_name  directamente asi "request.user.firts_name" pero esta forma te aseguros de que el tipo de perfil sea de profesor
except Profesor.DoesNotExist:
     print "no existe un profesor con este usuario"
```

esto mismo lo puedes hacer con estudiante. Espero haberte ayudado, me vas comentando lo que surja

Lo que puedes hacer es pasar un parametro mas por kwargs , por ejemplo tipo y supogamos que si es uno es profesor y si es dos es estudiante

```
def create_profile(sender,**kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        if kwargs['tipo'] == 1:
            user_profile =Profesor.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])
        else:
            user_profile =Estudiante.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])
```

ESta es una solucion de acuerdo a tu codigo pero lo ideal seria que crearas dos formularios y dos clases en el view, si se registra desde el formulario  Estudiante en el creas el perfil de estudiante y si es un profesor pues la de un profesor, como procesos separados vamos.

Comment: modifique la pregunta e incluí mi model.py espero q pueda ayudarme

Comment: acabo de modificar mi respuesta

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia y las molestias , ya entendí lo q me dices pero al tener 2 modelos perfil  estudiante y profesor como modifico la señal para q cuando cree un usuario sepa de q tipo lo quiero hacer

Comment: Es decir como lo tengo ahora en cuanto creo un usuario se crea un UserProfile pero al tener 2 como sería,

Comment: como estas creando ahora lso usuarios, desde admin o tienes algun tipo de formulario?

Comment: Por ahora estoy usando el admin, a Manera de prueba no pienso usarlo así porque no tiene sentido ya q primero tengo q crear el usuario con sus datos y después modificar el perfil y añadirle los datos, después q tenga resuelto lo de los dos tipos de perfil, quiero hacerlo con formulario para q cada persona sea estudiante o Profesor pueda registrarse..

Comment: si lo  haces desde  admin, es como lo has dicho primero crear el User y luego el Perfil de Estudiante o profesor, para hacerlo con form es mas sencillo por que solo lo tienes que programar una vez, al guardar el registro primero creas el User , luego el perfil y  finalmente lo relacionas, esto dependera de como gestiones tu formulario de registro, te recomiendo uses la clase base forms

Comment: Pero el problema lo sigo teniendo con los dos perfiles como le digo ahora cuando creo un usuario nuevo q tipo de perfil es

Comment: Cuando creo el usuario uso la función q esta en mi modelo create_profile para crear el perfil de q manera ahora siendo dos puedo crearlos

Comment: Te acabo de modificar mi respuesta

Comment: modifique la pregunta ahora si trabaja bien hasta ahora usando el admin, ahora voy a tratar de hacerlo usando formularios

Comment: Genial! me alegro haberte sido de ayuda, no olvides que tienes que crear un formulario para cada tipo de perfil asi sabras cual tienes que crear. Un saludos

Answer (score 0):

Una de las opciones que pudieras intentar es con una clase abstracta, la cual contenga atributos y métodos genéricos para todos los modelos que hereden de ella, y en las clases que hereden  puedes definir atributos propios

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class InfoBase(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True)
    # puedes definir N campos que necesites en las clases que hereden

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class EstudianteA(InfoBase):
    atributo1_estudianteA = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    atributo2_estudianteA = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class EstudianteB(InfoBase):
    atributo1_estudianteB = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    atributo2_estudianteB = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Profesor(InfoBase):
    atributo1_profesor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    atributo2_profesor = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Es importante acotar que la solución anterior no creara una tabla en BD para el modelo `InfoBase`, creará una tabla para cada clase que herede de ella la cual contendrá los atributos definidos en la clase `infoBase` y en la clase que le hereda

Del mismo modo si necesitamos diferenciar que tipo de usuario es, podemos implementar varios enfoques (es algo amplia tu pregunta, pero trataré de ir al grano)

**Utilizar Grupos de usuarios**

Puedes crear diversos grupos de usuarios (django.contrib.auth.models.Group), a los cuales añadir el usuario que recién crees, puedes tener un grupo llamado `Profesores` otro llamado `Estudiantes A` y `Estudiantes B`

Y en la vista donde creas los usuarios asignarlos, según cada situación

```
from django.contrib.auth.models  import Group
#
#
def creacion_usuarios_profesores(request):
    # resto del code 
    grupo_profesores = Group.objects.get(name="Profesores")
    objeto_recien_creado.user.groups.add(grupo_profesores)
    # otras acciones
    objeto_recien_creado.user.save()
```

De esa forma puedes mostrar, validar y ejercer diversas acciones, según el, o los grupos a donde este asignado el usuario

**Otra Opción**

Otra opción  que he visto, pero que en lo particular no me gusta, pudiera ser crear en la clase un atributo `tipo_usuario` relacionado a un nuevo Modelo llamado `TipoUsuario` donde almacenes los diversos tipos de usuario que tu consideres, y en base a eso puedas asignar para luego comparar

Recuerda que eso va a depender de tu enfoque de negocios y de las necesidades del proyecto

Espero sea de tu ayuda

Comment: Entiendo lo q dices pero como puedo q cuando yo quiera crear un usuario nuevo sepa de q tipo de perfil es, de la manera q uso ahora es usando un solo perfil y usando el método create_profile le asocio al usuario q se acaba de crear el perfil pero si fueran dos de q manera lo difenciaria

Comment: @PedroDiazLabiste puedes manejar que tipo de usuario es, segun los grupos de usuario a donde este asignado, tu pregunta es algo amplia, pero tratare de ir al grano para ayudar en lo que se pueda. modifiqué mi respuesta, espero sea de ayuda